# Why asp:DropDownList does not respond to code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ASP drop-down:

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlMain" name="searchPhys" style="width: 365px;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="BY PHYSICIAN" Value="0" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="BY LOCATION" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="BY SPECIALTY" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
<br /><br />
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlDrillDown" name="searchPhys" style="width: 365px;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am trying to make it interactive where if the first select option is changed the second will change as well based on the selection from the first select option.

My C# code looks like this:

```
public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    String cString;
    SqlConnection Conn;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    PopulatePhysician();
    //PopulateSpecialty();
    //PopulateLocation();

    }


    public void PopulatePhysician() {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getPhysicians", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
        //cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues = default(SqlDataReader);
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //if (!IsPostBack) {
            ddlDrillDown.DataSource = ddlValues;
            ddlDrillDown.DataValueField = "content_id";
            ddlDrillDown.DataTextField = "content_title";
            ddlDrillDown.DataBind();
            //set the default value for the drop down
            ListItem Item = new ListItem();
            Item.Text = "Select a Physician's Name";
            Item.Value = "0";
            //Item.Selected = True
            ddlDrillDown.Items.Insert(0, Item);
        //}
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }

    public void PopulateSpecialty() {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getSpecialties", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues = default(SqlDataReader);
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //if (!IsPostBack) {
            ddlDrillDown.DataSource = ddlValues;
            ddlDrillDown.DataValueField = "content_id";
            ddlDrillDown.DataTextField = "content_title";
            ddlDrillDown.DataBind();
            //set the default value for the drop down
            ListItem Item = new ListItem();
            Item.Text = "Select a Specialty";
            Item.Value = "0";
            ddlDrillDown.Items.Insert(0, Item);
        //}
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
    }

    public void PopulateLocation() {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getLocations", new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"]));
        cmd.Connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader ddlValues = default(SqlDataReader);
        ddlValues = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        //if (!IsPostBack) {
            ddlDrillDown.DataSource = ddlValues;
            ddlDrillDown.DataValueField = "content_id";
            ddlDrillDown.DataTextField = "content_title";
            ddlDrillDown.DataBind();

            //set the default value for the drop down
            ListItem Item = new ListItem();
            Item.Text = "Select a Location";
            Item.Value = "0";
            ddlDrillDown.Items.Insert(0, Item);
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Connection.Dispose();
        //}
    }

    public void ddlMain_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        switch(ddlMain.SelectedItem.Value) {
            case "0":
                PopulatePhysician();
                break;
            case "1":
                PopulateLocation();
                break;
            case "2":
                PopulateSpecialty();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When the page first loads, `PopulatePhysician();` works great by populating the select option. But when I call the `SelectedIndexChanged()` function, nothing happens.

How can I resolve it? Is the `case` statement correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't added any delegates to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Add `OnSelectedIndexChanged` to the parameters in the asp:DropDownList tag, like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ClientIDMode="Static" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMain_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ddlMain" name="searchPhys" style="width: 365px;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  >
```

*EDIT*

I just noticed you're actually missing the `AutoPostBack` event as well - it should be set to `true`, as updating the selection without submitting the form will not fire a postback event, unless `AutoPostBack` is set to true.

Comment: I can't do AutoPostBack, in that case the PopulatePhysician will load every time.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You're using `!IsPostBack` in your population statements, so there shouldn't be any issues it doing that. I recommend you wrap `Page_Load` in it instead, as you should be allowed to repopulate another list from the main selector.

Comment: I removed IsPostBack and still nothing

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge You shouldn't remove `!IsPostBack`, that's not the issue. Have you tried adding `AutoPostBack` to your `DropDownList`?

Comment: I have the `PopulatePhysician()` on page load and adding `AutoPostBack` reloads my page hence always populating the physician instead of what is selected. But yes I did add it and still nothing :/ I updated my question with the updated code and still nothing.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge make your `Page_Load` look like this instead: http://pastebin.com/PLYCGjBP , and then use the AutoPostBack feature.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52708/discussion-between-sebastian-job-bjornager-jensen-and-searchforknowledge)

Answer (score 2):

It needs `AutoPostback=true` on the Dropdown list

```
<asp:DropDownList AutoPostback="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlMain" name="searchPhys" style="width: 365px;" class="default" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the If (!IsPostBack) clause from your functions.  Check for that in page load, but not in each individual function.

Comment: I updated my code and still nothing. Please check my question with the updated code.

Comment: First, put the If (!IsPostBack) check in your Page_Load event.  That way, the PopulatePhysician(); call you have in Page_Load *only* fires the first time you come to the page.  After you have done that, add the AutoPostback = true to your initial DropDown list - it needs to post back so that it can fire the rest.

Comment: Should I add the `AutoPostBack="True"` to both of my dropdown list?

Comment: Ok I was able to fix it. But NOW what is happening is instead of refreshing the list with the parent dropdown the child dropdown just appends to the original list

Comment: DropDownLoad.Items.Clear(); solved the issue :) Thanks.